# CARES Act tax refund eligibility questions

Tags: discussion, questions

We currently have numerous questions, with a few new ones each day, basically asking "will I get stimulus check" relating to the CARES Act. The [stimulus](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stimulus) tag (is this even a useful tag?) currently has 20 questions.

Should we do one (or both) of the following?

1. Create a canonical *Who is eligible for stimulus payments under the CARES Act and when will the money be paid?* question to mark all (or some or most) of these as duplicates?
2. Create a CARES Act payment tag?

Comment: Up to 26 questions now. At this rate, it may soon exceed the 38 questions tagged sugar-daddy :)

Answer (score 5):

> 1. Create a canonical *Who is eligible for stimulus payments under the CARES Act and when will the money be paid?* question to mark all (or some or most) of these as duplicates?

Yes

> 2. Create a CARES Act payment tag?

No

Answer (score 3):

Both seem reasonable to me. Let me know if you need any mod help to make it happen.